# Linq Query after Where statement not returning relationship data

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

```
public List<Store> GetAllFriendsTopStores(long uid, List<long> users)
{
    using (var entities = new myEntities()) {
        var v = entities.DbUsers
            .Where( x => users.Contains( x.uid ))
            .Stores // i can't select stores here?  Why is this???
    }
}
```

In this case Stores is a navigation property... I need to be able to access the stores objects for my friends in this scenerio.

Comment: Is Stores a property on a `DbUser`?  Or on an entity?

Comment: it is a navigation property on user that relates to a DbStores table

Answer (score 1):

After `Where` you have `IEnumerable` collection, so if you have only one user as the result and want to access it - apply `Single()`

```
    var v = entities.DbUsers
        .Where( x => users.Contains( x.uid ))
        .Single()
        .Stores;
```

**UPD**:

```
    var v = entities.DbUsers
        .Where( x => users.Contains( x.uid ))
        .Select( x => x.Stores );
```

In this case you will get the collection of users' `Stores`.

**UPD 2**:

```
    var v = entities.DbUsers
        .Where( x => users.Contains( x.uid ))
        .Select( x => new { Stores = x.Stores, BllStore = new BllStore{a=x.a} );
```

If I understand you correctly - that is what you are looking for. After this you have the collection with anonymous objects, each of which has `Stores` and `BllStore` property.

Comment: your way does work... but what im trying to do is get a list of users, and then return the stores for all of them... is this possible?

Comment: lets say i wanted to do a select statement like x=>new BllStore{a=x.a} something like thiat, would i add a second select statement or is there a way to do it all in 1 statement.

Answer (score 0):

At the place you are attempting to use Stores, you are trying to call it on a filtered sequence (collection) of DbUser objects. You'd need to be in a context that gives you access to a single record to use that.

Comment: i understand now... is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do with a single statement?