# EF Linq - Loading Relationship Values after Where Statement Part 2

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

this is a second part to my first question posted here...

[Linq Query after Where statement not returning relationship data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757185/linq-query-after-where-statement-not-returning-relationship-data)

What Im trying to do is use linq to represent this data...

Get My Friends' Favorite stores, where store is an object that contains a list of the friends who also have favorited each store.  The relationship is basically a many to many of users and stores

I have started with a query like this...

```
entities.DbUsers.Where( x => users.Contains( x.uid ) )
```

At the end of this statement I don't have the context to access the stores objects that are attached to the friends, so i tried doing something like this...

```
entities.DbUsers.Where( x => users.Contains( x.uid ) ).Select( r => new Store(  ) )} );
```

however in this case the r is a DbUesr object, so i cant really build a store object from it very easily.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following code :

Assumed that "Stores" is the Association name inside Users for Stores.

```
var filteredUsers = entities.DbUsers.Where( x => users.Contains( x.uid ) ).Select( r => r.Stores);
```

Now if you access filteredUsers then it should give you the associated stores for that user. Also make sure that Stores is not being Lazy loaded.

Comment: this is an approach i considered, i need to be able to access the store data afterwards in its own "select" statement, like using a POCO object.. so Select(r=>r.stores) does not give taht ability to do something like r=>new Store(r.store.x),, i gues that is the question i am asking